# Hair particles causing cycles render to hang on 2.9

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I don't know if anyone else is having this issue but for some reason a hair particle system is causing cycles renderer to hang at the initializing stage and I have to force quit blender.

If I turn off the particle system the scene renders fine.
I've narrowed it down to the children section, I have it set simple which is the best look for the hair I'm rendering however if I set it to interpolated the scene renders fine but the look isn't what I want.

Can anyone help?

I'm using a Macbook pro 2018. OS Catalina 10.15.7
Blender version 2.91

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share your particle settings.

Comment: Probably your RAM memory isn't enough or your machine is not powerful enough to handle the scene, especially in cycles engine

Comment: Hair and particles will use a lot of ram. It is possible that you are pushing the scene past the resources available in your computer. Start with a lower number of particles and children, and see if that works. Then increase the number to a point where you get something you can live with, but that is not killing your computer.

Comment: Looks like memory limitation may be the issue here. The scene renders fine with just one character with hair. As soon as I add another that's when the rendering hangs. I'm surprised as I have 16gig on my machine and the same scene rendered fine in version 2.83

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting it seems I was wrong about the memory. I've learned that having too many particles definitely affects memory and render times.

To combat this I reduced the number of children by half which made a huge difference but then the hair looked too thin, so to compensate I thickened up the roots.

It seems that my system will alert me if blender is out of memory when using too complex meshes but not with hair particles. Also my render times have decreased significantly.